# What is the meaning of this line of code in C++?

Tags: java, c++

I'm trying to learn myself c++ and stumbled across this code. I wonder what this specific line of code does. I have some knowledge of Java and with my humble knowledge I could make something off all the other lines of code.

The specific line of code: `bool operator > (const path& l, const path& r) {return l.cost != r.cost ? l.cost > r.cost : l.dist > r.dist;}`

This is whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct path { int cost, dist, x, y; };
bool operator > (const path& l, const path& r) {return l.cost != r.cost ? l.cost > r.cost : l.dist > r.dist;}

int r, k;
vector<vector<int>> kaart;

path solve() {                                                  // dijkstra
    vector<vector<bool>> seen(r, vector<bool>(k, false));

    priority_queue<path, vector<path>, greater<path>> queue;
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) queue.push(path{ 0, 0, -1, i });

    while (queue.top().x != k - 1) {
        path p = queue.top();
        queue.pop();

        if (p.x < 0 || !seen.at(p.y).at(p.x)) {
            if(p.x >= 0) seen.at(p.y).at(p.x) = true;

            queue.push(                             { p.cost + kaart.at(p.y).at(p.x + 1), p.dist + 1, p.x + 1, p.y });
            if (p.x > 0) queue.push(                { p.cost + kaart.at(p.y).at(p.x - 1), p.dist + 1, p.x - 1, p.y });
            if (p.x >= 0 && p.y > 0) queue.push(    { p.cost + kaart.at(p.y - 1).at(p.x), p.dist + 1, p.x, p.y - 1 });
            if (p.x >= 0 && p.y < r - 1) queue.push({ p.cost + kaart.at(p.y + 1).at(p.x), p.dist + 1, p.x, p.y + 1 });
        }
    }

    return queue.top();
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> r >> k;

        kaart = vector<vector<int>>(r, vector<int>(k, 0));
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < k; l++) {
                cin >> kaart.at(j).at(l);
            }
        }

        path sol = solve();
        cout << i << " " << sol.dist << " " << sol.cost << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: with a compareto function?

Comment: there is no, java doesnt allow custom operator overloading

Comment: It seems you searched for a solution to a specific problem, and found some C++ code that you want our help translating. I suggest you instead research about the algorithm itself, not caring about finding code-snippets ([cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) is bad after all), and once you understand the algorithm you can implement it yourself in any language you please.

Comment: There are no single lines in coding. There is always context: like what is the final code supposed to do? In your case: you should probably define a class that wraps around the attributes that this operator is comparing. And then you provide a compareTo() method on that class.

Comment: I get the meaning and way of working of the algorithm. While researching about this problem I found this and I wondered how they solved this problem. I read the code and wondered what that line does. When is that compare function called?

Comment: comparing or even translating language features when considered in isolation is futile. You have to take the code as a whole, understand what it does, trash it, rewrite something that does the same in the other language. Make your last comment the question and it could be answered.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ statements

```cpp
struct path { int cost, dist, x, y; };
bool operator > (const path& l, const path& r) {return l.cost != r.cost ? l.cost > r.cost : l.dist > r.dist;}
```

defines an object and a comparison operator for comparing two of those objects.

The Java equivalent for comparing two objects directly, is to have the object implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

A C++ `struct` is like a Java class with `public` fields, so the equivalent Java code would be:

```Java
class Path implements Comparable<Path> {
    public int cost;
    public int dist;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Path that) {
        return this.cost != that.cost ? Integer.compare(this.cost, that.cost)
                                      : Integer.compare(this.dist, that.dist);
    }
}
```

Normally, you would change the fields to be private and add getter (and maybe setter) methods.

The comparison operator is used by the `priority_queue`, and the Java equivalent is the [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), which will use the `compareTo()` method.